# Wait till image is loaded and resized before triggering animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#body-background").ezBgResize();
$("#nav").animate({
        left: "-725px"
    }, 800, "easeOutCirc" );
    $("#page .home").animate({
            right: "0px"
    }, 800, "easeOutCirc" );
```

This is essentially my code.

The first line uses jQuery Easy Background Resize: (ref: http://johnpatrickgiven.com/jquery/background-resize/)

In the HTML, you put something like this:

```
<!-- This gets positioned absolutely so place it anywhere. -->
<div id="body-background"><img src="image/bg.jpg" alt="Bg"></div>
```

The problem I'm having is that the image takes so long to load the first time, the animations don't fire...and skip to the end. Anyway I can delay the animation till after the resize is complete?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: The site I'm working on: http://jsc.yondershorecreative.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best thing I can do is simulate the image preloader and wait for the load event of it:

```
// grab the background image object
var img = $('#body-background img');

// next, create a new hidden image in the background and bind to the load event
var nImg = $('<img>').bind('load',function(){
  // this is where your "After load" code would go
});

// next, give the image the same URL of the image for the background
// this will force the event to load up and call the load event
nImg.attr('src',img.attr('src'));
```

Works in [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/UhddM/1/) (Just change the number after the `?` in the image URL to simulate emptying cache). Let me know if that helps.

---

**Update** (Given commentary below)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#body-background').azBgResize();

  var homepageAnimation = function(){
    $("#nav").animate({
      left: "-725px"
    }, 800, "easeOutCirc" );
    $("#page .home").animate({
      right: "0px"
    }, 800, "easeOutCirc" );
  }
  $(window).load(function(){
    setTimeout(homepageAnimation,1000);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @Avinash: On a business-grade line here, needed something that wouldn't load in ~1sec. ;p Also, credits to [toast.net](http://www.toastnet.net) for their image (speed-test image).

Comment: I tried this method, but it's still not working. Suspect it's a quirk with background resizer.  Here's the actual site: http://jsc.yondershorecreative.com/  Any ideas?

Comment: @clifgriffin: Just curious, what about the site doesn't work? My initial visit to the site seemed fine (unless you mean that the nav comes in before the background's completed?)

Comment: That's exactly what I mean...I want to delay the nav till the bg loads. Arguably a poor design, but that's what has been asked of me.

Comment: @cliffgriffin: Well, given the background plugin is binding to window.load, maybe you can place your animation in there as well. I'm not sure how javascript's event stack works, but assuming that it's FIFO, the bg script should run first, then your code (placed beneath the background binding) would execute after. Maybe separate the animation off to a function and place a setTimeout within the window load just to be sure.

Comment: @clifgriffin: See my updated answer and try that. You have a lot of CSS/elements to reproduce for a test environment, but give that a god and see if it works (PoC from my previous comment)

Comment: Thanks, Brad.  I had to put this on hold but will check it this weekend and give you appropriate credit if it works. :)

Comment: @clifgriffin: Sounds good. Either way let me know, I'll be curious to know if that works out or not. ;-)

Comment: Works like a charm...interestingly, simply structuring it like you did fixed it.  The timeout proved unnecessary. Great stuff and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @clifgriffin: I kind of figured that JS would execute in order of FIFO. Just had to look at how the other scripts loaded and accommodate. Glad it worked out for you, and not a problem. Always glad to help! ;-)